# How to shutdown ubuntu server from shell script?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, shell-script

I wrote a simple shell script to shutdown an ubuntu server. Then I created a cron job to execute this script at 23:59 everyday.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo shutdown -h now
```

I got this error message:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

when I removed the sudo from the code, I got a different error message:

```
/home/qinking126/scripts/test.sh: line 3: shutdown: command not found
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the cron script is executable and also running as root, and replace `shutdown` by its full path given to you by:

```
command -v shutdown
```

On Ubuntu GNU/Linux (and GNU/Linux in general), it should be `/sbin/shutdown` :

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Note that adding a file named like `/etc/cron.d/midnight-shutdown` and containing:

```
59 23   * * *   root    test -x /sbin/shutdown && /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

should do what you want without the overhead of a full bash script. Here is the code to install this quickly:

```
echo '59 23 * * *   root    test -x /sbin/shutdown && /sbin/shutdown -h now' \
    | sudo tee '/etc/cron.d/midnight-shutdow'
sudo service cron reload
```

EDIT: To reply to your comment, another possibility of setting is:

```
echo '59 23 * * *   test -x /sbin/shutdown && /sbin/shutdown -h now' \
    | sudo tee '/etc/cron.d/midnight-shutdown'
sudo service cron reload
```

It is quite strange that cron print you this error message.

Comment: got this error message  "/bin/sh: 1: root: not found"

Comment: added another setting possibility.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the command "sudo halt" to  power off the Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enable `poweroff` (normally a sudoer command) in an ssh prompt for non-sudoers, by, as a sudoer, adding the +s flag to the command executable. Like so:

`sudo chmod a+s /usr/sbin/poweroff`

After this, non-sudoers were be able to power off the system, over ssh, or even via a shell script running in their name.